# Pairing probability (high school maths problem)

Tags: probability

Hi I am getting stuck on this probability question (all 3 parts) and since I don't have the answers for these, I really don't know where to start.

Team A plays team B in a chess match. Each team consists of four players. The match consists of four games where each member of one team is paired with exactly one member of the other team. Each game has three possible outcomes.

- a win for the player from team A (1 point for A, 0 points for B)
- a win for the player from team B (1 point for B, 0 points for A)
- a draw (1/2 point for B, 1/2 point for A)

i) Find the number of different ways in which the pairings can be made between the players of team A and team B.

ii) For a particular arrangement of pairs of players, find the number of different possible ways in which the outcomes of the four games can occur.

iii) Suppose that the players in team A and team B are evenly paired so that in each of the four games, the outcomes 'a win for A', 'a win for B' and 'a draw' are equally likely. For this particular pairing, find the probability that the overall match is drawn (i.e. a total of 2 points for each team).

Even though this is a high school maths problem, I have already learnt permutation, combination and binomial probability.
Thank you very much everyone!

Answer (score 0):

In all of these questions drawing a tree diagram may help.

For (i) think about how you can construct a pairing between the teams, pick an opponent for the first member, then the second and so on, how many choices of opponents are there at each stage of this construction? Using this information you can work out the number of pairings.

For (ii) you can encode the outcome of the four games with a four letter word using letters A,B,D; for example if team A wins in the first pair, team B wins in the second pair and the final two pairs draw, you can represent this outcome as ABDD. So counting how many words like this that you can make will give you the answer.

For (iii) what is the probability of one pair drawing? See if you can go from here.